# Visual Studio Code C/C++ refactoring (like if inversion)

Tags: visual-studio-code, refactoring

I miss lots of common refactoring in Visual Studio Code, and I can't get any set of refactoring features through the most common extensions.

Is there any known/common extension for Visual Studio Code to make refactoring like if statements inversion?

**Refactoring from:**

```c
   if (flag == TRUE) {
       printf("flag is true\n");
   } else {
       printf("flag is not true\n");
   }
```

**To:**

```c
   if (flag != TRUE) {
       printf("flag is not true\n");
   } else {
       printf("flag is true\n");
   }
```